# SetWaitableTimer function's Parameter 'lPeriod' is too short

Tags: windows, timer, msdn

In my system, I want to make a timer which can make a procedure call every day,I know API can meet my needs which named "SetWaitableTimer"
as I see from the msdn the "SetWaitableTimer" is defined as:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetWaitableTimer(
  _In_      HANDLE hTimer,
  _In_      const LARGE_INTEGER *pDueTime,
  _In_      LONG lPeriod,
  _In_opt_  PTIMERAPCROUTINE pfnCompletionRoutine,
  _In_opt_  LPVOID lpArgToCompletionRoutine,
  _In_      BOOL fResume
);
```

the lPeriod is the call period, and the type is long, value of long is from  –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. But the period I need is 24 hour, which is 24*60*60*10000000 , 10000000 is the length of one second. I do know how to solve my problem with this api, anyone can help me? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period is specified in milliseconds. There are 1,000 milliseconds in a second. So the period would be:

```
24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

Or 86400 * 1000 = `86,400,000`

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

*The period of the timer, in **milliseconds**. If lPeriod is zero, the timer is signaled once. If lPeriod is greater than zero, the timer is periodic. A periodic timer automatically reactivates each time the period elapses, until the timer is canceled using the CancelWaitableTimer function or reset using SetWaitableTimer. If lPeriod is less than zero, the function fails.*

SetWaitableTimer expects the DueTime to be given in 100 ns units. Unfortunately (**!**) it does does not accept periods in 100 ns units.